# Borders In Tables Not Lining Up

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Have a table set up, with a table nested in most of the cells, basically a pyramid matrix type structure.  Issue i'm having is the cell borders don't line up and in some cases double up, so i'm a little confused as how to fix it, having already used border specific values, ie, border-bottom and border-right, etc.

`Code`http://jsfiddle.net/WgRs6/5/

PS: I'm new to this so not sure how to post the CSS and HTML like in other user posts, where they're boxed in and you can scroll through, so just attached the

Comment: and what is the prob there???

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Comment: I don';t know how to put in the code question, that was the PS part of the question, any help you can provide as how to put in the HTML and CSS and i'll be able to do it next time

Comment: and the problem is the lines at the end of certain cells are off, so they don't line up; doesn't look like a table, all staggered

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you had a padding set..

So, remove the padding for the `<td>`

### Kindly check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/WgRs6/14/)

I,ve added

```
td{
    padding:0;
}
```

to your **css**

**UPDATE**

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/WgRs6/18/)

I've found out the problem in your code..You used several tables inside a `<td>` which created such a problem.In my fiddle i've done the whole thing with just one table using `rowspan` and `colspan`.Check it..

I'm sorry that i accidentally mis placed your table values while copy pasting and because it took a lot of time i was not able to complete the html.So kindly follow the same procedure inorder to generate the full table..

Comment: This doesn't change the position of the borders, they still don't line up

Comment: when i look at the end of each cell, the border around the red cells seem 1 pixel further in then the blue cells, so it's not a straight line down, but staggered

Comment: This is a project i've been given from higher up and they specifically asked to use a table inside a table, so applying these colspans and row spans still doesn't lineup the border from what i can see.  So i'm gathering the issue is that the table cells nested inside the bigger table's cells won't line up with their borders

Comment: the borders are lined up in the second fiddle...did you check that??http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/WgRs6/18/

Comment: Yes, they line up as you've used one table, my outline is to have a table nested within each cell of a table. Hence why using colspan and rowspan for whatever reason doesn't affect the size of the cells in the nested table, nor does it line anything up

Comment: the first line of my question is "Have a table set up, with a table nested in most of the cells, basically a pyramid matrix type structure", apologies if there was any misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `td` `padding` to `0px`:

```
td{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WgRs6/7/

Comment: They still don't line up, end of each row is still staggered as you look down the column